# Can I share the same KeyVault between Azure B2C, and Azure B2B (AAD)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-keyvault

A KeyVault seems to be tightly coupled to a [single AAD instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41451771/328397)

What guidance should I follow when I want to support Azure AD (B2C) and B2B / Work users?

I'm currently exploring [this solution](https://github.com/dstrockis/AAD-B2C-Hybrid) to help manage the independent sign in flows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet that gives access to an app or a user to secrets in the Key Vault:

> The following directories must all be the same Azure directory:
>
> -- The default directory of the Azure subscription in which the key vault resides.
>
> -- The Azure directory that contains the user or application group that you are granting permissions to.

So the Key Vault will be in a subscription and that subscription is attached to a single Azure AD. Any application that is given access must be from that directory.